# iterate over multiple lists inside an array in django template

Tags: django, python-2.7, for-loop, django-templates

I have two things, first is group and 2nd is group-item.

Group list is: `[<group1: group>, <group2: group>]`

Group Item list is:

```
[[<obj1: obj>, <obj2: obj>], [<obj3: obj>]]
```

where first set of objects belong to first group and second set belong to 2nd group.

I want to iterate these lists in `Django Template` and ouput is required something like this:

```
Group1
    obj1
    obj2

Group2
    obj3
```

Any help is appericiated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them together in the view and then iterate over the combined data structure in the template.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `Django` type of question certainly, it is `python list` manipulation type, the list items are Django objects.So, here I am giving example of how to manipulate the two list objects for the required format.

I assume,

#### Example input:

Instead of these example input `list`, you can use your `django list objects`.

```
list1 = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']
list2 = [['Item1','Item2'],['Item3','Item4'],['Item5']]
```

#### Snippet:

```
import itertools
In [19]: for g,i in itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2):
   ....:     print "Group:",g
   ....:     print "Items:",i
   ....:     
Group: Group1
Items: ['Item1', 'Item2']
Group: Group2
Items: ['Item3', 'Item4']
Group: Group3
Items: ['Item5']
```

#### Refer these:

[zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)